# JavaScript sets and value objects

Tags: javascript, set, identity, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

I want to create a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of [value objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) in JavaScript. The problem is that in JavaScript equality is based on identity. Hence, two different objects with the same value will be treated as unequal:

```js
var objects = new Set;

objects.add({ a: 1 });
objects.add({ a: 1 });

alert(objects.size);   // expected 1, actual 2
```

How do you work around this problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094680/user-defined-object-equality-for-a-set-in-harmony-es6

Comment: @elclanrs The only problem with that is the overhead associated with stringifying and parsing data.

Comment: In one of my libraries, I have my own Map implementation, which is at least API compatible. I simply use the `toString` method as has function, which allows me to treat arrays (of primitives) like tuples. That doesn't work out of the box for objects of course.

Comment: Why use sets when MDN says specifically that `The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.` (note `unique`). Either have something different about the objects or don't use sets.

Comment: @BardiHarborow Why use sets? I want a set of value objects, that's why. I know what the specification says, thank you very much. Uniqueness is guaranteed by the `Set` data type itself and not what you add to it. For example, `var i = 0; while (i < 10) objects.add(1);` will only add `1` to the set `objects` once. What do you mean by "have something different about the objects"? I don't want to have anything different about the objects. I want them to be the same object without having to worry about them having the same identity. Don't use sets? Well, thank you very much. That solves my problem.

Comment: @BardiHarborow In what world would any sane person want two same valued objects to be repeated in a set?

Comment: Yeah, well, that's exactly why my response was so sharp. Sorry about that.

Comment: @BardiHarborow Then why are you arguing? You make absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify`:

```js
var objects = new Set;

objects.add(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
objects.add(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));

alert(objects.size);
```