# Javascript Set: any way to override comparison between elements?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

A `Set` handles 2 empty objects as different, e.g.:

```js
let s = new Set([ {} ]);
s.has({}); // false
```

This is expected, but it would be useful to compare based on their contents instead, as is possible in various other languages.

**Is there any way to override the `Set`'s internal comparison operator?**

Comment: Also, this was asked 12h ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29272134/218196. Please use the search before you ask a new question (there are not that many es6 questions).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to override the `Set`'s internal comparison operator?

No. `Set.prototype.has` is defined like this:

> [**23.2.3.7 - Set.prototype.has ( value )**](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-set.prototype.has)
>
> The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *S* be the **this** value.
> 2. If [Type](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*S*) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 3. If *S* does not have a [[SetData]] [internal slot](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) throw a TypeError exception.
> 4. Let *entries* be the [List](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-list-and-record-specification-type) that is the value of *S*’s [[SetData]] [internal slot](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots).
> 5. Repeat for each *e* that is an element of *entries*,
>
>    1. If *e* is not empty and [SameValueZero](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-samevaluezero)(*e*, *value*) is **true**, return **true**.
> 6. Return **false**.

Therefore, `Set` must compare using [SameValueZero](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-samevaluezero) comparison, and you can't change that.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. The comparison used for Set instances is almost the same as the `===` operator, except that `NaN` can be put in a Set (once), meaning that `NaN` is treated as being `===` to itself for that purpose.