# Set Comparability for Objects in ECMA6 JS

Tags: javascript, set, comparator, equality, ecmascript-6

I've been using a set to store and retrieve simple objects which represent coordinates.

```
// Creates a point in hex coordinates
  function hexPoint(q, r) {
    this.q = q;
    this.r = r;
  }
```

I am generating these points multiple times, so that I have easy coordinate pairs to pass around, but I wish to be able to store them in such a way that I do not store duplicate coordinates.

The ECMA 6 Set object relies on references to test object equality, so I am wondering if there is a way to supply this set with a comparable function so that I may allow it to test equality for new objects with the same fields. Otherwise, is there something else I can do to avoid re-implementing this data structure?

Comment: plain objects don't have repeats, and you can use your numbers as keys, sticking q+r together to make a "unique" key that you can look for in hexPoint() before returning a new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add an `isEqual(otherPoint)`? It might look something like:

```
function HexPoint(q, r) {
  this.q = q;
  this.r = r;
}

HexPoint.prototype.isEqual = function(otherPoint) {
  return this.q === otherPoint.q && this.r === otherPoint.r;
}
```

Then you can make instances of `HexPoint` with:

```
var point = new HexPoint(...);
if (point.isEqual(someOtherPoint)) {
  ...
}
```

A [similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094680/user-defined-object-equality-for-a-set-in-harmony-es6) points out no native option exists yet.

Comment: Will the Set be able to use the isEqual function to perform its equality checks? As I understand it, the implementation of set only checks the reference and does not perform any other checks. I want the set to be able to maintain its own uniqueness without me having to check for it.

Comment: @MichaelVonHippel I think you have to build a say a UniqueSet class if you want that. It would check on `add` if the `Object` was already present. If using `HexPoint`, you'd probably want to add an `isEqual` like above and use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing that check seems like needless complexity to add(since I would have to iterate over all existing elements anyway.) I guess the alternative is to use a factory for all hexpoints or simply make my own set that implements hashing.