# Details on JS Set

Tags: javascript, set

I just found out that JS had a built-in Set (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and I was mindblown, but I was wondering how this was implemented, and what running times it had. I come from Java, but I'm pretty sure this is the case in C# as well: Is the Set the same a HashSet in Java? The operations I care about are add, contains, and remove, so ideally, I would want JS to use a HashSet or TreeSet implementation.

Also, I wanted to know if I could add Dates to the Set, or if I could somehow add a custom class with my own compare function.

If it says somewhere in the docs and I just missed it, a quick link would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference from Java is that you cannot implement your own equality tests for set members. Iterating through set members is always done in insertion order.

You can add objects of any type to a Set instance, but two different Date objects will be distinct, no matter what point in time they represent (including the same millisecond timestamp).

Comment: Note: The "always in insertion-order" can be accounted for by equating it to Java's `LinkedHashSet`, rather than plain `HashSet`. But yes, [the lack of support for arbitrary user-defined equality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36558813/364696) is unpleasant.

Comment: Also note: Technically, the ECMA spec doesn't require average case `O(1)` performance. It suggests a hash table implementation, but [allows "other mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection."](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set-objects) The guarantee of insertion order iteration does mean it would be pretty silly to use another option (tree sets being useful because they *don't* preserve insertion order), but it's possible.

Comment: @ShadowRanger right, it's almost certainly something like a linked hash set, but like with everything else that's an implementation decision.